# Use of "take a course of action to somebody"

Tags: verbs

The screenshot is taken from *Riddick 2013*:

[image]

Usually we would say take something concrete to sombody, like taking a cake, gift.. to somebody. We could also say take somebody a cake, gift, etc.

But in this context, this bounty hunter intends to take a '*hunt*' to Riddick. Would it be OK to say "We'll take him the hunt by day"?

Let's generalize this use. In some other conceivable contexts, could we say "we'll take the punishment/demoralization/fishing to him"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the coach of a sports team speaking to his squad before the game:

> I want you to leave your hearts out there on the field. I want you to give
>   110%.  I want you to take it to them with all you've got!

"Take it to them..." or "bring it to them..." is macho lingo that refers to the marshaling and directing of efforts in an aggressive, overpowering manner. "It" there need not have a specific referent.

P.S. If you were going to use a specific noun with "take|bring {noun} to ..." we would tend to use a prepositional phrase:

**We'll bring the fight *to him*...**

rather than

**We'll bring *him* the fight...**

The preposition *to* reinforces the adversarial element.

P.S. With simple "him", as in "bring him {something}", the bringing is for his benefit.